# Как взять из текстового документа первое число?

Tags: python

Есть текстовый документ, в нём хранятся множества пар чисел, а перед этими парами стоит число, показывающее количество этих пар. Пример:

```
4

1 6

8 5

9 1

16 7
```

Мне нужно узнать первое число (В данном случае это `4`) или же посчитать количество строк. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    n = int(file.readline())
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = map(int, file.readline())
        print(a, b)
```

в начале открываем файл, а потом читаем первую строчку